# where should questions about questions asked at stack physics exchange be asked?

Tags: discussion, scope

Where and how would I ask a question such as: "what do you consider to be the most profound question asked at stack.exchange.physics while you've been here?"

On the one hand I don't think it falls into the category of the sort of questions that should be asked since there is no right or wrong answer and is merely an opinion. Yet on the other hand, it seems to be similar to questions asked about book recommendations and could be tagged as wiki-community.

How would the moderators deal with it?

Answer (score 6):

In general:

> Where should questions about questions asked at stack physics exchange be asked?

On meta, i.e. right here.

The particular question you're asking about, though, is way too open-ended and not constructive, so it'd be a good candidate to get closed. Of course, we're not as active about "policing" meta questions as we are on the main site... still I think something like that would be best left in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/physics).